# Parallel process for spatial weights matrix production in R

Tags: r, sf, parallel-processing

I have an sf object `pData` that is rather large (300,000 polygons) and I am trying to produce spatial weights for each polygon:

```
tilesNb=knn2nb(knearneigh(st_centroid(pData), k = 2))
tilesWeights=nb2listw(tilesNb, style="W")
```

But the first line ran for hours and then timed out. Is there a way to conduct this step through a parallel process? I tried modifying [code from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40235264/deterime-neighbours-list-in-parallel), but I couldn't quite figure out how to modify their technique for my simpler approach to neighbor matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not need to parallelise if you can use a faster nearest neighbour algorithm. The FNN package has such. Let's test it:

Make 100,000 points:

```
> xy = cbind(runif(100000),runif(100000))
```

And get the 2 nearest neighbours.

```
> kxyF = FNN::knn.index(xy, k=2)
```

I blinked and it was done. It gives me a 100,000 x 2 matrix of indexes showing the nearest points as rows of `xy`:

```
> str(kxyF)
 int [1:100000, 1:2] 82552 71951 71149 16282 14576 88806 87619 19744 55467 60788 ...
```

Let's try with `knearneigh`:

```
> kxySP = knearneigh(xy, k=2)
```

I'm still waiting. I've typed this whole answer up to here and still waiting...I give up. Here's the output for a smaller example so we can compare the output:

With `FNN::knn.index`:

```
> str(kxyF)
 int [1:10000, 1:2] 1618 2026 2426 7932 9634 5257 9092 6751 4080 3892 ...
```

Note you only get the index. `knearneigh` also does the work of computing the distances:

```
> str(kxySP)
List of 5
 $ nn       : int [1:10000, 1:2] 1618 2026 2426 7932 9634 5257 9092 6751 4080 3892 ...
 $ np       : int 10000
 $ k        : num 2
 $ dimension: int 2
 $ x        : num [1:10000, 1:2] 0.3509 0.5742 0.0598 0.5555 0.7335 ...
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "knn"
 - attr(*, "call")= language knearneigh(x = xy, k = 2)
```

but the indexes look the same as with the fast `FNN` function.

If you want the distances, they can be computed and since you know the indexes you only have a few distances to compute.

Yes there's might be a little but of manipulation to get the structure you get from `nb2listw` but I don't see any computational complexity there.

Comment: It's funny that you posted this approach. I was just looking for a way to speed up the raster distance function and found that rewriting the function so that it uses RANN is a MASSIVE improvement in speed. Do you think there is much difference between RANN and FNN? I have a few package functions that use RANN and am wondering if I should switch to FNN. It looks like they both use the Arya and Mount ANN library but there can be notable differences in R implementation.

Comment: @JeffreyEvans don't know, I do know that FNN is faster than using `dist` :)